# RecyclerView gets crashed [IllegalArgumentException] when use notifyItemChanged from Handler using Runnable

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I'm using `RecyclerView` as a list to show songs that can be downloaded. Each item has `ProgressBar` in its `View`. When the download starts, then I use a `Handler` to notify each item to update the `ProgressBar` to show the song download progress.

> **Q1. Is this is a correct way to do it or Is there any other way to do it more appropriately.**
>
> **Q2. RecyclerView gets crashed when we use `adapter.notifyItemChanged(position);` to update the content of single item. It is called from a `Handler` using `Runnable`. But, the log don't show any traces for my code. Why?**

Below is the log for this issue:

```
05-06 19:09:45.804: E/AndroidRuntime(32115): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
05-06 19:09:45.804: E/AndroidRuntime(32115): java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Tmp detached view should be removed from RecyclerView before it can be recycled: ViewHolder{41b7bec0 position=6 id=-1, oldPos=-1, pLpos:-1 update changed tmpDetachedundefined adapter position no parent}
05-06 19:09:45.804: E/AndroidRuntime(32115):    at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$Recycler.recycleViewHolderInternal(RecyclerView.java:3861)
05-06 19:09:45.804: E/AndroidRuntime(32115):    at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView.removeAnimatingView(RecyclerView.java:779)
05-06 19:09:45.804: E/AndroidRuntime(32115):    at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView.access$5300(RecyclerView.java:127)
05-06 19:09:45.804: E/AndroidRuntime(32115):    at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$ItemAnimatorRestoreListener.onAddFinished(RecyclerView.java:8228)
05-06 19:09:45.804: E/AndroidRuntime(32115):    at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$ItemAnimator.dispatchAddFinished(RecyclerView.java:8573)
05-06 19:09:45.804: E/AndroidRuntime(32115):    at android.support.v7.widget.DefaultItemAnimator$5.onAnimationEnd(DefaultItemAnimator.java:239)
05-06 19:09:45.804: E/AndroidRuntime(32115):    at android.support.v4.view.ViewPropertyAnimatorCompatJB$1.onAnimationEnd(ViewPropertyAnimatorCompatJB.java:47)
05-06 19:09:45.804: E/AndroidRuntime(32115):    at android.view.ViewPropertyAnimator$AnimatorEventListener.onAnimationEnd(ViewPropertyAnimator.java:973)
05-06 19:09:45.804: E/AndroidRuntime(32115):    at android.animation.ValueAnimator.endAnimation(ValueAnimator.java:1012)
05-06 19:09:45.804: E/AndroidRuntime(32115):    at android.animation.ValueAnimator.access$400(ValueAnimator.java:51)
05-06 19:09:45.804: E/AndroidRuntime(32115):    at android.animation.ValueAnimator$AnimationHandler.doAnimationFrame(ValueAnimator.java:623)
05-06 19:09:45.804: E/AndroidRuntime(32115):    at android.animation.ValueAnimator$AnimationHandler.run(ValueAnimator.java:639)
05-06 19:09:45.804: E/AndroidRuntime(32115):    at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:776)
05-06 19:09:45.804: E/AndroidRuntime(32115):    at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:579)
05-06 19:09:45.804: E/AndroidRuntime(32115):    at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:547)
05-06 19:09:45.804: E/AndroidRuntime(32115):    at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:762)
05-06 19:09:45.804: E/AndroidRuntime(32115):    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:725)
05-06 19:09:45.804: E/AndroidRuntime(32115):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
05-06 19:09:45.804: E/AndroidRuntime(32115):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:153)
05-06 19:09:45.804: E/AndroidRuntime(32115):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5297)
05-06 19:09:45.804: E/AndroidRuntime(32115):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
05-06 19:09:45.804: E/AndroidRuntime(32115):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
05-06 19:09:45.804: E/AndroidRuntime(32115):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:833)
05-06 19:09:45.804: E/AndroidRuntime(32115):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:600)
05-06 19:09:45.804: E/AndroidRuntime(32115):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

I searched to find the solution for this but couldn't find any appropriate answer.

Comment: im facing this right now. this is a problem with the animator. sometime it throw sometime it doesn't, i dont know how to fix this :(

Comment: Hi @amrut-bidri if this or any answer has solved your question please consider [accepting it](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234/179419) by clicking the check-mark. This indicates to the wider community that you've found a solution and gives some reputation to both the answerer and yourself. There is no obligation to do this.

Comment: 6 years passed and I can still encountered this FATAL today. Nice job on making stable Views, Google.

Answer (score 19):

i had the same issue,i could handle it by disabling the animator of recyclerview:

recyclerView.itemAnimator = null

Comment: this also fixed my issue, but what if you really need to animate the changes? :/

Comment: You need to also restore it, no? Otherwise you will lose the nice animations when the list of items is changing, no?

Answer (score 15):

We also had this issue on our application, and after a *really* long debugging session we found out that it was caused by `adapter.setHasStableIds(true)`

We removed the offending line and the issue is finally gone.

Hope it helps.

Comment: Solved my issue, though the getItemId() returned correct unique ids for data items.

Comment: What if I need `SetHasStableIds` to be true? Is there another way?

Comment: Good question. In that case, you mustn't call `notifyItemChanged` from a `Runnable`. You should refer to @Gonmator answer.

Answer (score 14):

For me the issue was resolved after I removed `animateLayoutChanges=“true”` from the parent ViewGroup of the recyclerview.

Answer (score 7):

Some people here say that "android:animateLayoutChanges" should not be set to true, but I didn't set it, and setting it to false didn't help either.

Anyway, for some reason, in my case, replacing ConstraintLayout with LinearLayout as the parent of the RecyclerView has fixed it.

Another alternative is that before I let the adapter of the RecyclerView have any changes on it or have any changes on the RecyclerView's parent (in my case I switch between views in ViewAnimator), I added this check:

```
                   if (recyclerView.isAnimating)
                        Handler().post {
                            adapter.items = it.listItems
                            adapter.notifyDataSetChanged()
                        }
                    else {
                         adapter.items = it.listItems
                         adapter.notifyDataSetChanged()
                         }
```

For some reason this alternative didn't work for me on POC, so I suggest the LinearLayout solution instead, or use this in case you clear the data or switch to another view like I do:

```
                val itemAnimator = recyclerView.itemAnimator
                recyclerView.itemAnimator = null
                clearItems()
                recyclerView.itemAnimator = itemAnimator
```

```
    fun clearItems() {
        items.clear()
        recyclerView.adapter!!.notifyDataSetChanged()
        viewSwitcher.setViewToSwitchTo(R.id.emptyView)
    }
```

I reported about this issue to Google [here](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/148720682). The POC and the workarounds (that work for me) are available there too.

The POC shows that this occurs if the RecyclerView is inside ConstraintLayout, which is inside ViewAnimator. The scenario is that while the RecyclerView is animating some of its views (removing a single item, for example), I clear all of its items and switch to another view inside the ViewAnimator.

Answer (score 6):

I faced the same problem but turned out the reason was calling `scrollToPosition`. The solution that worked for me after many attempts was to call `notifyDataSetChanged` before scrolling (all from the UI thread of course). Maybe it will help someone.

Answer (score 5):

Since this is the first post to come up I'll post another solution to the problem which helped in my specific case: 
I was hiding the `parentview` containing the `recyclerview` using

`parentView.setVisibility(View.GONE);`

recyclerview does not like that, apparently if you want to hide a view which contains a recyclerview, you can only use `View.INVISIBLE`.

Comment: Could the downvoter please explain? I thought it was fairly common to comment other solutions in threads if this is a common problem with different causes.

Comment: Good find Ole. This was the problem for me. I had to make the recycler view invisible (not GONE) - and poof, crash is gone.

Answer (score 4):

`adapter.notifyItemChanged(position);`must be called from the main thread

instead of your Handler use the Handler with mainLooper

```
    new Handler(Looper.getMainLooper()).post(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            //HERE
        }
    });
```

Comment: I always take care of these things to call them in UI thread. That's not a problem

Answer (score 4):

There are several workarounds to the problem:

1. Call to `notifyDataSetChanged()` instead `notifyItemChanged()`. It is the less efficient way to solve it.
2. As pointed by Henrique de Sousa, remove the line `adapter.setHasStableIds(true)` prevents the problem.

But the real solution (as commented by southerton), if the adapter is stable, is to implement and correctly `getItemId()`, honouring the "hasStableIds" value set.

Answer (score 4):

If recycler view parent is `ConstraintLayout` inside `ViewAnimator/ViewSwitcher` try to:

1. set horizontal constraints in recycler view
2. set recycler view `layout_width` to `0dp`

or if recycler view is direct child do the same for `ViewAnimator/ViewSwitcher`.

Answer (score 2):

the only solution, which worked for me,

```
    fun RecyclerView.executeAfterAllAnimationsAreFinished(
        callback: (RecyclerView) -> Unit
) = post(
        object : Runnable {
            override fun run() {
                if (isAnimating) {
                    //if isAnimating() returned true itemAnimator will be non-null
                    itemAnimator!!.isRunning {
                        post(this)
                    }
                } else {
                    callback(this@executeAfterAllAnimationsAreFinished)
                }
            }
        }
)
```

Explanation : It waits till itemAnimator stopped animating and provide callback with recyclerview.

Comment: Can you add some context around this? When do we call this extension?

Answer (score 2):

If you're using a RecyclerView inside a ConstraintLayout. This issue can be solved by adding horizontal constraints to the recycler and changing its width to 0dp.

```
<androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
                android:id="@+id/recyclerView"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="0dp"
                app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Well I had this code in my activity.

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    getWindow().requestFeature(Window.FEATURE_ACTIVITY_TRANSITIONS);
    getWindow().setAllowEnterTransitionOverlap(true);
    getWindow().setAllowReturnTransitionOverlap(true);
    getWindow().setExitTransition(new MaterialSharedAxis(MaterialSharedAxis.Z, true).setDuration(250));
    getWindow().setEnterTransition(new MaterialSharedAxis(MaterialSharedAxis.Z, true).setDuration(250));
    getWindow().setReenterTransition(new MaterialSharedAxis(MaterialSharedAxis.Z, false).setDuration(250));
    getWindow().setReturnTransition(new MaterialSharedAxis(MaterialSharedAxis.Z, false).setDuration(250));
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
...
}
```

This crash happened for me when I tried to go to an external App and I had a recyclerview in my activity.

It seems like the recycler view has some issues with Animations.

What i did to solve this was to give up having the exit animation by commenting that line out

```
// getWindow().setExitTransition(new MaterialSharedAxis(MaterialSharedAxis.Z, true).setDuration(250));
```

Answer (score 0):

Several points:

1. To get beautiful animations use diffUtils instead of stableId - both of them are interchangable, but diffUtils better in performance and preferrable (stableId is an old approach).
2. The crash happens when DefaultItemAnimator is in use, so if your code doesn't contain list.itemAnimator = null you can catch it anytime.
3. The crash happens (at least in my case) when list items updating in a fast manner and there is a change animation that is not ended yet. The fix is to use list.itemAnimator?.endAnimations() before items update.