# Some time my app crashed while updating progress of uploading video in recyclerView row -Android

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, crash, inotifypropertychanged

I'm uploading a video and showing progress in `recyclerview` , we can upload more then one video & showing their progress *individually* and if we change page or move into *app* uploading should continue (not stop).

**Problem occur** - app crashed some time while updating progress in `recyclerView` (`recyclerView` in fragment with TAB layout  + viewPager)

I'm using broadcast receiver for it

**Code is below**

```
 try {
        for (int i = 0; i < postList.size(); i++) {
            if (postList.get(i).getId().equals(postId)) {
                postList.get(i).setProgress(result.getProgress());
                profileListAdapter.notifyItemChanged(i);
            }
        }

    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

**Logcat**

```
Fatal Exception: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Tmp detached view should be removed from RecyclerView before it can be recycled: ViewHolder{cc90564 position=1 id=-1, oldPos=-1, pLpos:-1 update tmpDetached no parent}
   at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$Recycler.recycleViewHolderInternal(RecyclerView.java:5238)
   at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView.removeAnimatingView(RecyclerView.java:1198)
   at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$ItemAnimatorRestoreListener.onAnimationFinished(RecyclerView.java:10834)
   at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$ItemAnimator.dispatchAnimationFinished(RecyclerView.java:11334)
   at android.support.v7.widget.SimpleItemAnimator.dispatchAddFinished(SimpleItemAnimator.java:289)
   at android.support.v7.widget.DefaultItemAnimator$5.onAnimationEnd(DefaultItemAnimator.java:242)
   at android.support.v4.view.ViewPropertyAnimatorCompatJB$1.onAnimationEnd(ViewPropertyAnimatorCompatJB.java:47)
   at android.view.ViewPropertyAnimator$AnimatorEventListener.onAnimationEnd(ViewPropertyAnimator.java:1114)
   at android.animation.ValueAnimator.endAnimation(ValueAnimator.java:1239)
   at android.animation.ValueAnimator.cancel(ValueAnimator.java:1140)
   at android.view.ViewPropertyAnimator.cancel(ViewPropertyAnimator.java:427)
   at android.support.v4.view.ViewPropertyAnimatorCompatICS.cancel(ViewPropertyAnimatorCompatICS.java:102)
   at android.support.v4.view.ViewPropertyAnimatorCompat$ICSViewPropertyAnimatorCompatImpl.cancel(ViewPropertyAnimatorCompat.java:464)
   at android.support.v4.view.ViewPropertyAnimatorCompat.cancel(ViewPropertyAnimatorCompat.java:1063)
   at
```

**Showing this error**

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Tmp detached view should be removed from RecyclerView before it can be recycled: 
ViewHolder{cc90564 position=1 id=-1, oldPos=-1, pLpos:-1 update tmpDetached no parent}
```

**Note:**

I'm not using in my app anywhere `getSwipeableContainerView` and `adapter.setHasStableIds(true)`.

**Design of row**:
Like this `recyclerView` row
[image: Like this recyclerView row]

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30078834/recyclerview-gets-crashed-illegalargumentexception-when-use-notifyitemchanged

Comment: @Nilesh i already checked it, but not finding any solution

Comment: Try to notify the rows when the fragment containing the list is visible to user. using setUserVisibleHint().

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try `notifyDataSetChanged()` instead of `notifyItemChanged(i)`.